# TFS - Use a template from TFS 2017 to TFS 2010 [migration TFS 2017 to 2010]

Tags: migration

I customized a build process activity with an implementation of a Code Activity in the workflow in a Template from TFS2017. Unfortunately I have to use this Code Activity in TFS 2010.
I have this mistake when I "copy/paste" my template from TFS2017 to TFS2010 keeping the structure of the Code Activity:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \BCA3\BP8BA: The type ‘InArgument(mtbc:BuildParameter[])’ of property ‘AutomatedTests’ could not be resolved.
```

My structure TFS2017:

[image]

The solution for the custom activity TFS2017

[image]

The workflow in TFS2017 (the custom activity is called CopyActivity below):

[image]

How can I manage this?

**EDIT : error with template TFS2010 and VS2017:**

The build process failed validation. Details: Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.BuildNumber". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "DropBuild AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(BuildDetail.DropLocation)". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.DropLocation". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.BuildNumber". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Name". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "associatedChangesets". Type 'Changeset' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "associatedChangesets". Type 'Changeset' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "treatTestFailureAsBuildFailure And (BuildDetail.TestStatus = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Failed)". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. 'Client' is not a member of 'Build'. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.TestStatus = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Unknown". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. 'Client' is not a member of 'Build'. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.CompilationStatus = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Unknown". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. 'Client' is not a member of 'Build'. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "testAssemblies.Count() > 0". 'Count' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of String)'. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.RequestedFor". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "String.Format("Build Failure in Build: {0}", BuildDetail.BuildNumber)". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(BuildDetail.DropLocation)". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "If (platformConfiguration.IsEmpty Or BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations.Count = 1, BuildDetail.DropLocation + "\logs", If (platformConfiguration.IsPlatformEmptyOrAnyCpu, BuildDetail.DropLocation + "\logs\" + platformConfiguration.Configuration, BuildDetail.DropLocation + "\logs\" + platformConfiguration.Platform + "\" + platformConfiguration.Configuration))". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "String.Format("{0}@$/{1}", LabelName, BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.TeamProject)". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "String.Format("$/{0}", BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.TeamProject)". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "WorkspaceName.Length > Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.RepositoryConstants.MaxWorkspaceNameSize". 'VersionControl' is not a member of 'TeamFoundation'. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "WorkspaceName.Substring(0, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.RepositoryConstants.MaxWorkspaceNameSize).TrimEnd()". 'VersionControl' is not a member of 'TeamFoundation'. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "String.Format("The workspace name '{0}' exceeds the maximum allowed limit of '{1}' characters. Truncating it to match the maximum limit.", WorkspaceName, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.RepositoryConstants.MaxWorkspaceNameSize)". 'VersionControl' is not a member of 'TeamFoundation'. Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Id, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.LinkingUtilities.DecodeUri(BuildAgent.Uri.AbsoluteUri).ToolSpecificId, BuildAgent.ServiceHost.Name)". Type 'IBuildDetail' is not defined. 'LinkingUtilities' is not a member of 'TeamFoundation'. Type 'IBuildAgent' is not defined. Type 'IBuildAgent' is not defined.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How did you "Copy\Paste"? Did you directly check in the template into TFS 2010?

Comment: I mean I add the solution with the custom activity into TFS2010. I check in the template into TFS 2010.

Comment: Did you do the last step(Enable your custom build process) in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850441(v=vs.120).aspx#Enable your custom build process

Comment: Yes I did, and I point towards for instance bin/Debug (where is Sourcet8.dll). Maybe it's because I'm using a template from TFS 2017?

Comment: That may causes that, Use a higher version template in the old version TFS. why not download the build process template from tfs2010 and custom it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you 'copy' the whole structure from TFS 2017 to TFS 2010.
Follow [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850441(v=vs.120).aspx#Create%20a%20custom%20build%20process%20activity) to make sure that the custom activity project and and the .dll of your custom activity is checked into your TFS 2010.

Don't forget to the last step(**Enable your custom build process**) in that document. In the build controller, set the version control path to custom assemblies path.

Here is another blog talks about these error: https://nkdagility.com/tfs-2012-issue-tf215097-an-error-occurred-while-initializing-a-build-for-build-definition/

**Update:**

Becasue you want to use Template for TFS 2010. You'd better download a default template from TFS 2010 and customize it. To custom the default template from TFS 2010, please use VS2010. And about those reference, please use 10.0.

Comment: Following the document, I restarted with a Template from TFS2010. When I launch the Build Definition I get these errors: Type 'IBuildAgent' is not defined. Type 'IBuildAgent' is not defined.

Comment: @FrankVDB Did you add the 2 reference in your project. `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client .dll` and
`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow .dll`

Comment: Yes I did, I exactly follow  these steps 3 times

Comment: @FrankVDB what version of the build assembly you use, 10.0 or 14.0?

Comment: I'm using the version 10.0

Comment: @FrankVDB So you get this error when you open the template in VS 2017  not getting this error during build? If so, do your team have lower version of Visual Studio(VS 2010), try to open it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142127/discussion-between-tingting0929-msft-and-frankvdb).

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the version between TFS2010 and VS2017, I finally figure out warnings, step by step, and each time I figured out one error, another appears. So, I begin with the VS2010.

Comment: @FrankVDB Sorry for the late response. I let you to try VS2010 is because I suspect that the compatibility between VS2017 and TFS 2010. As you know, TFS 2010 is a little bit old.  I have updated my reply according to the comments we discuss with each other.